# Python nested subprocess real time output

Tags: subprocess

My requirement is to invoke sh file from a python file but in a nested way
parent.py ---> child.py ---> 1.sh

```
1.sh
----
for i in {1..100}
do
 sleep 2
 echo $i
done
```

```
child.py
--------
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

def executecmd(cmd):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
       output = p1.stdout.readline()
       if p1.poll() is not None:
           break
       if output:
          print output.strip()

    p1.wait()
    if p1.returncode == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
script_home=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
child_prog=script_home + '/1.sh'
cmd=child_prog
executecmd(cmd)
```

```
parent.py
---------

#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os

def executecmd(cmd):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
       output = p1.stdout.readline()
       if p1.poll() is not None:
           break
       if output:
          print output.strip()

    p1.wait()
    if p1.returncode == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
script_home=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
child_prog=script_home + '/child.py'
cmd=child_prog
executecmd(cmd)
```

when invoked like child.py ---> 1.sh
I get the real time o/p from 1.sh

But when invoked like parent.py --> child.py --> 1.sh
I dont get the real time o/p.
parent.py gives the display when the child.py has completed.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it..

```
parent.py
---------
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
script_home=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
child_prog=script_home + '/child.py'
cmd=child_prog
os.system(cmd)
```